# Error: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: angularjs, npm, protractor

I am trying to follow the tutorial at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial  and have an error running the command

```
npm run protractor
```

Here is the console log:

> > Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
> >     Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> >
> > C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat>npm run protractor
> >
> > > angular-phonecat@0.0.0 preprotractor C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat
> > >       npm run update-webdriver
> > >
> > > angular-phonecat@0.0.0 preupdate-webdriver C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat
> > >       npm install
> > >
> > > angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat
> > >       bower install
> > >
> > > angular-phonecat@0.0.0 update-webdriver C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat
> > >       webdriver-manager update
>
> selenium standalone is up to date. chromedriver is up to date.
>
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat
>   protractor test/protractor-conf.js
>
> util.puts: Use console.log instead Using ChromeDriver directly...
>   Error: spawn UNKNOWN
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
>       at exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
>       at C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:173:23
>       at C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1243:15
>       at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\prom ise.js:1539:20)
>       at notify (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:362:12)
>       at [object Object].then (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:414:7)
>       at Object.webdriver.promise.when (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:639:18)
>       at C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:172:20
>   ==== async task ==== WebDriver.createSession()
>       at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:131:49)
>       at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:111:30)
>       at Object.createDriver (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:460:30)
>       at ChromeDriverProvider.getDriver (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\chrome.js:67:27)
>       at C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:221:35
>       at _fulfilled (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
>       at C:\GIT\angular-practices\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:525:49

Can you tell me where the problem is?

Here is my protractor conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

  specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  chromeOnly: true,

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Comment: can you post your protractor conf.js file

Answer (score 4):

For those who are on a Mac and getting this error, the following open issue can cause this: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/476

The solution is provided by ciekawy.
In

`node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/files/file_manager.js` or

`node_modules/protractor/webdriver-manager/built/lib/files/file_manager.js`

add the following code at line 166:

```
fileUrl.url = fileUrl.url.replace(/_m1/, '');
```

You will then need to update the chrome drivers to pick up the change. If using NRWL's NX monorepo management tools:

```
npx webdriver-manager clean
npx webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome=<version from chrome://versions>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your conf.js file change to **chromeOnly: false**

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

  specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  chromeOnly: false,

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

similer issue you can find here [#176](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/176)

Comment: hello , i went through the exact steps in https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial . and i was able to run `npm run protractor'` command successfully . I think you must have missed one or two steps . did you run the `npm start` command from the root folder to install the npm packages ? i will update the steps in my answer . let me know whether did you do the exact thing ?

Comment: Hi, I reset the changes to step 3 doing git checkout -f step-3. Then I run:   npm install;    npm run update-webdriver ;   npm run protractor