# Visual Studio Code: Spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

There are multiple other posts reporting this, but they are related to javascript frameworks, etc.

I get this error when opening any `.php` extension file and the error pops up at the top and it always blocks the tabs, very annoying.

[image]

Similar posts, but does not solve:

- [visual studio code nodejs request 'launch': cannot launch target (reason: spawn node ENOENT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808246/visual-studio-code-nodejs-request-launch-cannot-launch-target-reason-spawn)
- [Error: spawn UNKNOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786793/error-spawn-unknown)
- [Node-webkit child spawn UNKNOWN error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809808/node-webkit-child-spawn-unknown-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your config file (F1 + config and select settings json) and search for:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": null,
```

I have the same error and it was because I have pointing to the wrong file:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.ini"
```

it must point to (in my case):

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue today. If someone is using Ubuntu and XAMPP then your path is `/opt/lampp/bin/php`. I was using `/opt/lampp/php` therefore VSCode was showing **Error spawning PHP: spawn EACCES** error as soon as my files were loading in the editor.

Either you are using **XAMPP** or have installed PHP alone on Ubuntu Linux, you can always run `whereis php` in your terminal to locate php path.

The problem has also been discussed here https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense/issues/25

I hope this helps developers!